# HP Smartcard keyboard not working

Tags: keyboard, smartcard

I have an HP Skylab Smartcard keyboard and from what I can tell, the device itself is recognized by the system. It's just that when I try to test login it does not ask me for my PIN. Instead, it returns an error as shown below:

```
$ uname -a
Linux cistron 5.15.0-41-generic #44~20.04.1-Ubuntu SMP Fri Jun 24 13:27:29 UTC 2022 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
$ pkcs11-tool --list-slots
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x0): Chicony HP Skylab USB Smartcard Keyboard [HP Skylab Smartcard...
  token label        : PIV_II
  token manufacturer : piv_II
  token model        : PKCS#15 emulated
  token flags        : login required, PIN pad present, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized
  hardware version   : 0.0
  firmware version   : 0.0
  serial num         : 421381972a89c3f5
  pin min/max        : 4/8
$ pkcs11-tool --test --login
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
error: PKCS11 function C_Login failed: rv = CKR_FUNCTION_CANCELED (0x50)
Aborting.
```

For comparison, I have a different card reader that works fine:

```
$ pkcs11-tool --list-slots
Available slots:
Slot 0 (0x0): SCM Microsystems Inc. SCR 3310 [CCID Interface] 00 00
  token label        : PIV_II
  token manufacturer : piv_II
  token model        : PKCS#15 emulated
  token flags        : login required, rng, token initialized, PIN initialized
  hardware version   : 0.0
  firmware version   : 0.0
  serial num         : 421381972a89c3f5
  pin min/max        : 4/8
$ pkcs11-tool --test --login
Using slot 0 with a present token (0x0)
Logging in to "PIV_II".
Please enter User PIN:
 <...>
```

This looks like some kind of config issue but I can't tell what.

Answer (score 0):

Apparently this is related to pinpad as reported [here](https://github.com/LudovicRousseau/CCID/pull/65).
The solution was to upgrade the version of `libccid` to the latest. I downloaded a `.deb` file from [here](https://packages.debian.org/search?keywords=libccid) and installed it using `dpkg`. With version 1.5 the smartcard reader is working as expected.